# Why am i getting different results after port scanning my own IP multiple times

Tags: python, linux, networking

I was watching a tutorial teaching me to write a script with python that scans for open ports for an IP address.

The tutor ran a similar script as I wrote and predicted what ports should be open for him. my problem is, every time I run my script using my own IP address (using the `python3 myscript.py 127.x.x.x`) I get different results.
the script I ran on Linux:

```
#!/bin/python
  
# Our goal is to write a script that scans all the ports to an ip and finds the open one!

import sys 
import socket
from datetime import datetime

size = len(sys.argv)
if size !=2:
 print("You wrote the argument wrong! format : python3 script.py\
 Victim's domain or ip")
 sys.exit()
victim = socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[1])


print("$"*40)
print("Searching for open ports on victim: {}".format(victim))
print("Start time: " + str(datetime.now()))
print("$"*40)

try:
  for port in range(1,65000):
   #print("checking {}".format(port))
   x=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
   result = x.connect_ex((victim,port))
   if result == 0:
    print("Port {} is open!".format(port))
   x.close() 
except socket.error:
   print("Could not connect")
   sys.exit()
except socket.gaierror:
  print("Invalid domain")
  sys.exit()
```

First time I ran my script I got no open ports, the second time I got 2 open ports, and the third time I got only 1 open port.
I only have a shallow knowledge of networking so a simple explanation of why unlike the tutorial video I watched my ports are sometimes open and sometimes closed is much appreciated.

Comment: You should wrap individual attempts in your `try`/`except` block rather than the entire loop. The way you're doing it means it'll stop looping on your first failure. Also, naming your destination address `victim` implies that this isn't being done in good faith.

Comment: The victim naming was just for fun, if that's against the rules, tell me so i change it.

Answer (score 1):

The Python documentation on sockets (https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) states:

Running an example several times with too small delay between executions, could lead to this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

This is because the previous execution has left the socket in a TIME_WAIT state, and can’t be immediately reused.

There is a socket flag to set, in order to prevent this, socket.SO_REUSEADDR:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
```

the SO_REUSEADDR flag tells the kernel to reuse a local socket in TIME_WAIT state, without waiting for its natural timeout to expire.

Comment: The problem is the entire loop wrapped in a `try`/`except` though. So, at your first closed port, the entire loop will abort.